# upload image to a API without input form file

Tags: angularjs, file, upload, httprequest, multipartform-data

I have a problem with the upload image of my mobile application.
I am using angularJs and cordova's plugins.
I am working on the mobile application and the serveur API is alread created with play framework.
The API is waiting for a multipart/form-data to receieve a file and uploading it.
this post request is fonctionnal with Rest API and the files are correctly received with the multipart/form-data Content-type.
I can not use the input file in the HTML like this :

```html
"<input type="file" name="nam">"
```

So I am trying to do the same with angular js but We have a problem.

```js
var data =  new FormData();
var image = $cordovaFile.readAsText(cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory , "Anis.jpg");

image.then(function (success) {
  for( var key in success){
    data.append(key,success[key]);
  }
  var reponse = $http.post(server, data , { 
    transformRequest : angular.indentity,
    headers : { 'Content-Type' : undefined},
  });
```

In the API the error returned is that the Body's request is null.

I would to know how should I send a file with the content-type multipart/form-data to an API.